# Как решить проблему - AttributeError: 'Stream' object has no attribute 'donwload' -pytube - aiogram

Tags: python, pytube

Проблема в жирной строке, не пойму проблему... Делаю бота для скачивания Ютуб видео

```
async def download_youtube_video(url,message,bot):
    yt = YouTube(url)
    stream = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension="mp4")
    **stream.get_highest_resolution().donwload(f'{message.chat.id}', f'{message.chat.id}_{yt_title}')**
    with open(f"{message.chat.id}/{message.chat.id}_{yt.title}", 'rb') as video:
        await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video, caption="*Вот ваше видео *", parse_mode="Markdown")
        os.remove(f"{message.chat.id}/{message.chat.id}_{yt.title}")
```

Comment: "Как решить проблему?": 1) Помещайте код в соответствии  с правилами сайта (я отредактировал). 2) Помещайте полный стейк-трейс ошибки. 3) Анализируйте код самостоятельно хоть немного. 4) Хоть немного надо знать английские термины - нет слова "donwload", есть "download".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'Stream' object has no attribute 'donwload'

Это значит, что нету метода `donwload()` в классе `Stream`.

Почему нет? Потому, что вы сделали опечатку - правильное имя есть `download`.

Итак, правильно (и красивее, в двух строках:

```
stream.get_highest_resolution().download(f'{message.chat.id}',
                                         f'{message.chat.id}_{yt_title}')
```

Еше раз: Вы применили метод `donwload()`, который не существует, вместо правильного `download()`.